# How do I remove an element that does not satisfy a condition from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to remove multiples of 2 from a list. How do I do it?

```
a = list(range(1, 11))
print(a)
for ele in a:
    if ele % 2 == 0:
        a.pop(ele)
print(a)
```

Before the condition, `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

After the condition, I am expecting `a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`
But I get this error `IndexError: pop index out of range`

How do I get the indexes of the various multiples of 2 to pop them out??
I am a beginner.

Comment: Do not modify a list you iterate over !

Comment: The argument to pop doesn't do what you're expecting. See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: instead of removing create new list with elements which you want to stay.

Comment: As @furas said, don't just make a list and remove elements to make it what you want. Make the list from scratch how you want it (Ex: `a = [x for x in range(1, 11) if x % 2 != 0]`

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pop` on the list you are iterating on, you are modifying that list and you will run into issues like this, a better approach might be to create a new list and put your odd elements in that list.
In addition, you are using `pop` on using the value of the list instead of using it on the index which is incorrect. (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
a = list(range(1, 11))
odd_list = []
for ele in a:
    if ele % 2 != 0:
        odd_list.append(ele)
print(odd_list)
#[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: Apologies for the ignorance, but I am not sure if it is off topic.  The question was doing something fundamentally wrong, and I was just trying to give an example of what was wrong in the question, and tried to provide a correct solution.

Comment: In addition, folks are doing the same in the comment section above. I just provided an approach in form of an answer

Comment: As does the dupe for modifying a list you iterate over. Beside that its only 50% of the error - he uses `pop` on a value, not on the index of the value to be removed. Wich also has got dupes...

Comment: Did you read the link ?   What you should do: **cast a down vote, vote to close** (flag to close if you're under 3K rep), **_comment and explain why their question is bad_ and _how to fix it_**, use the tour, the help, maybe even a chat session
Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want.

Comment: I did read the link, and I don' think the question is off topic/bad. The user has provided an example and showed what error he got by using it, in addition mentioning he is a beginner. I have seen worse questions then this answered on SO. Also if the question is bad, I am sure it will be closed, and then I will delete my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191746/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-patrick-artner).

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am actually new with Stackoverflow and python programming in general, so pardon.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you :)